# can you use a rank as an outcome in a regression?

Tags: wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, ranking, ranks

I have data where people ranked their preferences for products A to J (ten in total), so I have 10 variables now for product A, B, C, ... , which all range from 1 to 10.

I'm wondering if it's ok to link a variable (e.g., age) to each rank.
Put it super simple, I'd be doing something like

lm(rankA ~ age, data)
lm(rankB ~ age, data) etc.

But I'm not sure about doing this since each of the ranks are clearly dependent on each other.
So even if the real effect is with only one of the product (the older you are, the more you like product A), I might still get something significant with other products just because ranking A highly will naturally lead to placing all other products at lower ranks.

Is this a legit concern and is there a way to address this?

Comment: How do you intend to interpret or make use of the results?

Comment: I'd want to say, for example, that older people had greater preference for the product A. But I'm not sure if a significant effect of age in that regression is truly showing some link between age and the product A or was just affected by a significant link between age and some other products (B or C or D...)

Comment: Is this something I don't need to worry about if I'm going to present the results on all ten products?